# Access object variable in Java Nashorn

Tags: java, javascript, nashorn

I have an object in my script, that contains fields and methods. I can call the methods in Java with `invokeMethod()` but can't seem to get the content of the fields of the object. I've got this JavaScript code:

```
var Test = { 
    TestVar: "SomeTest", 

    TestFunc: function() {
        print("Hello");
    }
};
```

In this Java Class:

```
import javax.script.Invocable;
import javax.script.ScriptEngine;
import javax.script.ScriptEngineManager;
import javax.script.ScriptException;

public class ScriptTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
        ScriptEngine engine = manager.getEngineByName("JavaScript");

        try {
            engine.eval("var Test = { TestVar: \"SomeTest\", TestFunc: function() { print(\"Hello\");}};");
        } catch (ScriptException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        }

        System.out.println(engine.get("Test"));
        System.out.println(engine.get("Test.TestVar"));
        System.out.println(engine.get("Test[TestVar]"));
        System.out.println(engine.get("Test[\"TestVar\"]"));

        Invocable inv = (Invocable) engine;

        try {
            inv.invokeMethod(engine.get("Test"), "TestFunc");
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ScriptException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

This gives me the output

```
[object Object]
null
null
null
Hello
```

Is there any way I can access the `TestVar` variable directly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Either:

```
engine.eval("Test.TestVar");
```

or

```
((JSObject)engine.get("Test")).getMember("TestVar");
```

should work.